# gcloud function: Could not find local artifact: How to solve?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

My cloud function code, is a maven-jar-project. It depends on other internal maven jar, so I have added that dependency to the pom.xml.

Expected:  I expect that the dependent jars will be automatically included in the cloud function deployment,  however I get an error "could not find artifact". Local compilation & running does not have any issue.

I don't want to copy paste those dependency sourcecode directly to my gcloud maven project. [bad ]

```
[INFO] Installing <removed>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.659 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-10T16:31:39-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------



>gcloud functions deploy response-adapter --entry-point fun.pubsub.<removed> --runtime java11  --memory 512MB --trigger-topic <removed>
 --env-vars-file env.yml


Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...-
For Cloud Build Stackdriver Logs, visit: 

Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: ...maven-plugin-2.2.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/tools/appengine-plugins-core/0.8.1/appengine-plugins-core-0.8.1.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar (521 kB at 375 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.21/snakeyaml-1.21.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar (502 kB at 357 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/tools/appengine-maven-plugin/2.2.0/appengine-maven-plugin-2.2.0.jar (76 kB at 53 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.19/commons-compress-1.19.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/tools/appengine-plugins-core/0.8.1/appengine-plugins-core-0.8.1.jar (236 kB at 164 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar (85 kB at 59 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.21/snakeyaml-1.21.jar (299 kB at 205 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.19/commons-compress-1.19.jar (615 kB at 416 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar (209 kB at 141 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/functions/invoker/java-function-invoker/1.0.2/java-function-invoker-1.0.2.jar (4.2 MB at 2.6 MB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.127 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-10T20:35:09Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gcf-removed-adapter: Could not resolve dependencies for project gcf-demo:gcf-removed-adapter:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact myadaptor:removed-mapper:jar:1.0-
SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException; Error ID: efa79f31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to [deploy from JAR](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-deploy#deploy_from_a_jar). Like that, you create a JAR with all the dependency already included in it (maven shade). No resolution at deployment time, only get your JAR and put it in Cloud Functions.